# How to properly delete hard links on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, links

I have created a hard link to a file in `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`, but after deleting it, I cannot create it again using `mklink`. The error says the file already exists. How do I properly delete this hard link, so that I may be able to create it again?

Comment: How did you delete it? Does the hard link still exist?

Comment: @DavidPostill I pressed the delete button it. I did some research, and that seems to be the correct way to delete it.